# How to clean the MySQL database on a daily basis

Tags: mysql, database

So, I have some kind of records in my database that should be deleted after 24 hours. How do I make my MySQL database to update itself? Is this even possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write cron jobs for that.

In linux you can use crontab for that [documentation](http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)

On Windows you can set cron jobs like [this](http://drupal.org/node/31506)

Answer (score 0):

```
0 0 * * * mysql -u USER -pPASSWORD -h HOST DATABASE < path/to/sql/script
```

look into [`man crontab`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/)